# trailing Stop Calculation for a strategy

Tags: programming, quant-trading-strategies, algorithmic-trading, trading-systems

I have converted pine script (UT-Bot by Yo_adriiiiaan) strategy to python but facing some errors. It requires TRA calculation and trailing stop calculation. Problem is that `talib.ATR()` function returns array with some values and also `NaNs`, the variable `nLoss` dependent on ATR() return value also has some real values and `NaNs` therefore I cannot compare them for calculating positions if I run the code it produces error that `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
Can anyone guide me on what I have done wrong and modify my code? Thaks

```
from tokenize import Double
import talib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import deque
import csv
import numpy
import array as arr
# Parameters
keyvalue = 3
atrperiod = 14
buffer_size = 20  

# Initialize arrays
src = deque(maxlen=buffer_size)
high = deque(maxlen=buffer_size)
low = deque(maxlen=buffer_size)

xATRTrailingStop = deque()
pos = deque()

# Retrieve real-time data (only last 20 atr period is 14)
def update_price(close):
    src.appendleft(close)

def update_high(hval):
    high.appendleft(hval)

def update_low(lval):
    low.appendleft(lval)

# Calculate ATR and trailing stop values in real-time
def calculate_trailing_stop():
   
    highArray=numpy.empty(buffer_size, dtype=float)
    lowArray =numpy.empty(buffer_size, dtype=float)
    srcArray =numpy.empty(buffer_size, dtype=float)
    

    i=0
    for records in high:
        highArray[i]=float(records)
        i=i+1    
    
    i=0
    for records in low:
        lowArray[i]=float(records)
        i=i+1
    
    i=0
    for records in src:
        srcArray[i]=float(records)
        i=i+1

    xATR = talib.ATR(highArray, lowArray, srcArray, atrperiod)
    nLoss = keyvalue * xATR
    print("xATR")
    print(xATR)
        
    print("nLoss")
    print(nLoss)

    xATRTrailingStop = numpy.zeros_like(srcArray)
    pos              = numpy.zeros_like(srcArray)
    
    for i in range(1, len(srcArray)): # for i in range(1, len(srcArray)):
         if srcArray[i] > xATRTrailingStop[i-1] and srcArray[i-1] > xATRTrailingStop[i-1]:
            a=float(xATRTrailingStop[i-1] )
            b=float(srcArray[i])  - (nLoss) 
            if ( a > b ) :
             xATRTrailingStop[i] = a 
            else:
             xATRTrailingStop[i] = b      
        
        elif srcArray[i] < xATRTrailingStop[i-1] and srcArray[i-1] < xATRTrailingStop[i-1]:
            a=float(xATRTrailingStop[i-1])
            b=float(srcArray[i]) + float(nLoss)
            if ( a < b ):
             xATRTrailingStop[i] = a 
            else:
             xATRTrailingStop[i]=b 
        else:
            if srcArray[i] > xATRTrailingStop[i-1]:
                xATRTrailingStop[i] = float(srcArray[i]) - nLoss
            else:
                xATRTrailingStop[i] = float(srcArray[i] )+ nLoss

        if srcArray[i-1] < xATRTrailingStop[i-1] and srcArray[i] > xATRTrailingStop[i-1]:
           pos[i] = 1
        elif srcArray[i-1] > xATRTrailingStop[i-1] and srcArray[i] < xATRTrailingStop[i-1]:
         pos[i] = -1
        else:
             pos[i] = pos[i-1]

        # Readind records one by one as live data from a file
with open('test8Jun23.csv', newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  #row = next(reader)
  for row in reader:
   highs_data=  row[2]
   lows_data=   row[3] 
   price_data = row[4]
   update_price(price_data)
   update_high(highs_data)
   update_low(lows_data)
   print(highs_data)
   print(lows_data)
   print(price_data)

   if len(src) >= buffer_size:
     print("calculate_trailing_stop() called")
     calculate_trailing_stop()
 
   else:
       print("Length <")
```